# What the difference between java HttpsURLConnection and python HTTPSConnection?

Tags: java, python, https

I want to port the open source project [android-market-api](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) from java to python. But now I've stucked in the https problem.
When I use HTTPSConnection to request `https://android.clients.google.com/market/api/ApiRequest`, it always return 403. And after some debug, I think may be there's something difference between java HttpsURLCollection and python HTTPSConnection.

Python port:

```
headers = {
    'Cookie': 'ANDROIDSECURE=' + auth_key,
    'User-Agent': 'Android-Market/2 (sapphire PLAT-RC33); gzip',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
    'Accept': 'text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('android.clients.google.com')
conn.request('POST', '/market/api/ApiRequest', 'version=2&request=' + urlsafe_b64encode(data), headers)
```

Origin java code:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
    };

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
{
    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        return true;
    }
});

URL url = new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/market/api/ApiRequest");
HttpsURLConnection cnx = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
cnx.setDoOutput(true);
cnx.setRequestMethod("POST");
cnx.setRequestProperty("Cookie","ANDROIDSECURE=" + this.getAuthSubToken());
cnx.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android-Market/2 (sapphire PLAT-RC33); gzip");
cnx.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
cnx.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
String request64 = Base64.encodeBytes(request,Base64.URL_SAFE);
String requestData = "version="+PROTOCOL_VERSION+"&request="+request64;
cnx.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestData.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
OutputStream os = cnx.getOutputStream();
os.write(requestData.getBytes());
os.close();
```

Comment: You need `conn.getresponse().read()` before making the next request. To produce `x-www-form-urlencoded'` content you could use: `urllib.urlencode(dict(version=2, request=data))`.

Comment: highly recommend you look into using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) instead of httplib

Comment: You should read the Javadoc before, or indeed instead of, asking such questions. The difference is that they are not the same. There's really nothing else to be said.

Comment: @EJP: As far as I can tell both code fragments should produces exactly the same http requests (even TLS parts both do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

403 means that the request is successful i.e., ["the provided credentials were successfully authenticated but that the credentials still do not grant the client permission to access the resource"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) e.g., without correct headers, body I get `400` not `403`.

Here's a more complete example on how to [make https request using httplib](https://gist.github.com/1841962#file_http_post_httplib.py).